# chrome extension contextMenu contextType includes browser_action didn't mathch documentUrlPatterns

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I create a contextMenu with contexts is ['all'] and documentUrlPatterns is ['*://*/*.pdf'].It works well in pages.But it always appear in browser_action even throught the page url's suffix isn't '.pdf'. I want this contextMenu don't appear in browser_action when page url don't endsWith '.pdf'. How to resolve this problem?

contextMenu create code:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  id: 'PDF_TOP',
  title: 'PDF编辑/打印/转换',
  contexts: ['all'],
  documentUrlPatterns: ['*://*/*.pdf']
})
```

contextMenu in page behavior:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp740.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmtJa.png)

contextMenu in browser_action beahvior:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yffi7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m91Zr.png)

Comment: It's not implemented: documentUrlPatterns doesn't influence the browser_action context.

Comment: Is this in the official Google document? @wOxxOm

Comment: This is a known bug, it's even reported somewhere in https://crbug.com.

Comment: thank u！！！@wOxxOm

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to [chrome.tabs.onActivated](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onActivated) and add or remove the context menu based on if the current page is PDF. It won't show in browser_action.

You can refer to the code below:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (info) {
    var tab = chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, function (tab) {
        if (tab.url.indexOf(".pdf") > 0) {
            chrome.contextMenus.create({
                "id": "PDF_TOP",
                title: "PDF test/print",
                contexts: ["all"]
            });
        } else {
            chrome.contextMenus.remove("PDF_TOP", null);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't want to use this method, it's so complex. It also need to listen to when current tab's url is updated.